# Where to put settings in a JQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

The [Default and Options section](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Defaults_and_Options) from the docs on JQuery plugin authoring, say to include settings like this:

```
(function( $ ){

  $.fn.tooltip = function( options ) {  

    // Create some defaults, extending them with any options that were provided
    var settings = $.extend( {
      'location'         : 'top',
      'background-color' : 'blue'
    }, options);

    return this.each(function() {        

      // Tooltip plugin code here

    });

  };
})( jQuery );
```

But further down, like in the [Data section](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Authoring#Data), the way of building the plugin changes and it isn't clear how to declare and initialize settings anymore.

**Do they get thrown in the init method like this? And if so, how does another method access them?**

```
  var methods = {
    init: function(options) {

      // no idea if this is the right place for settings
      var settings = $.extend({}, $.fn.myPlugin.defaultSettings, options || {});

      return this.each(function() {
       ....
      });
    },
    displaySettings: function() {
      console.log('WTF to do?');
    }
  ...
```

Comment: Your last snippet looks pretty close to what i would suggest, assuming later on you have `$.fn.myPlugin.defaultSettings = { ... }`

Comment: I do, as I read it was a best practice to declare them such.  But with the last snippet I can't seem to access the settings from another function - e.g. `console.log(this.settings)` - a scope issue I'm sure.

Comment: where are you storing the settings? It isn't a magic variable, you have to store it somewhere, and then pull it from that storage as needed.

Comment: I thought it would be stored within each MyPlugin instance, which is why I'm confused about where to declare the settings variable and how to reference it.  I'm used to traditional Classes and Objects, this functions and hash syntax I find confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd take a look at this article: [jQuery Plugin Design Patterns](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#jquerypluginpatterns)

There's also [an accompanying Github repository](https://github.com/addyosmani/jquery-plugin-patterns/tree/master/patterns) with all of the examples.

Comment: A very useful resource, thanks.  I've seen these (and countless boilerplates/patterns elsewhere) and find them to be a little overwhelming.  I'm not sure how they compare to the recommended method on the jQuery site but that's likely out of the scope of this particular question.

Answer (score 0):

This line is probably what you're looking for. It checks if a method was passed through as a parameter or an object with options in it.

```
if ( methods[method] ) { //Check if a method was passed
    return methods[method].apply( this, Array.prototype.slice.call( arguments, 1 ));
} else if ( typeof method === 'object' || ! method ) { // Check if options were passed
    // If Options passed, apply them to the .init method where it accepts arguments. 
    // In the example it doesn't show the init method utilizing the options.
    return methods.init.apply( this, arguments ); 
} else {
    $.error( 'Method ' +  method + ' does not exist on jQuery.tooltip' );
}
```

If options were passed then you would use the same code from above in the init method:

```
var methods = {
    init: function(options) {
        var settings = $.extend( {
            'location'         : 'top',
            'background-color' : 'blue'
        }, options);
...
```

You typically 'init' a plugin as your first method, so the options are there for that. Normally you wouldn't pass options with methods like 'destroy'.

Comment: I have that and most of the other code included in the Data section of the docs and understand how to instantiate the plugin passing settings.  What I'm unclear on is which method to set the settings in  (init seems to be the winner so far) and how to reference them from another function.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me:

```
(function ( $ ) {
    var methods = {
        init : function(options) {
            var settings = $.extend({
                some_setting: true
                ,some_other_setting: true
            }, options );

            var _this = this;
            _this[0].pluginNameSettings = settings;
            // rest of your init method here
        } // end of init method
        ,some_method: function( ) {
            $(this)[0].pluginNameSettings.some_setting;
            // rest of your method here
        }
    }

    $.fn.dropDownMenu = function(methodOrOptions) {
        if (methods[methodOrOptions]) {
            return methods[ methodOrOptions ].apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
        } else if (typeof methodOrOptions === 'object' || ! methodOrOptions) {
            // Default to "init"
            return methods.init.apply(this, arguments);
        } else {
            $.error('Method ' +  methodOrOptions + ' does not exist on jQuery.dropDownMenu');
        }
    };
}( jQuery ));
```